# Async Binding Thumbnail Image in UWP

Tags: c#, gridview, uwp, windows-10, windows-10-universal

I'm developing internal file manager in my UWP app. I'm showing StorageFolder's content in a GridView with calling this method:

```
gridView.ItemsSource = await storageFolder.GetItemsAsync();
```

Also, I have an item template for visualizing a file/folder item look linked to the the GridView. I have a Image object in this template. I want to bind StorageFolder's thumbnail image to this Image object's `Source` property. However, `GetThumbnailAsync()` is an asynchronous method, not a property. How can I do this?

Comment: Take a look at [Stephen Cleary's blog post](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn605875.aspx).

Comment: Thanks @Romasz, but it looks for MVVM applications on WPF,Asp.Net and Windows 8 / 8.1 runtime. Some libraries looks missing in Universal App Runtime.

Comment: The most important thing in the blog is how to deal with async methods and properties with Task pattern. Basing upon that I think you should be able to make thumbnail work with properties. What libraries are you missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Also, I have an item template for visualizing a file/folder item look linked to the the GridView. I have a Image object in this template. I want to bind StorageFolder's thumbnail image to this Image object's Source property.

I think you can firstly get the thumbnail then convert it to image, so can it be the source of `Image` control. I think what you need is like this:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <local:ThumbnailToImageConverter x:Key="cvt" />
    </Grid.Resources>
    <GridView x:Name="gridView">
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <Image Source="{Binding Thumbnail, Converter={StaticResource cvt}}" Stretch="None" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="0,5" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    </GridView>
</Grid>
```

Code behind and class for binding model:

```
private ObservableCollection<Model> Collection = new ObservableCollection<Model>();

protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    var files = await KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.GetFilesAsync();
    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        var thumbnail = await file.GetThumbnailAsync(ThumbnailMode.PicturesView, 100);
        Collection.Add(new Model { Name = file.Name, Thumbnail = thumbnail });
    }
    gridView.ItemsSource = Collection;
}

public class Model
{
    public StorageItemThumbnail Thumbnail { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Code of `ThumbnailToImageConverter`:

```
public class ThumbnailToImageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        BitmapImage image = null;

        if (value != null)
        {
            StorageItemThumbnail thumbnail = (StorageItemThumbnail)value;
            image = new BitmapImage();
            image.SetSource(thumbnail);
        }
        return (image);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Since I used `PicturesLibrary` in my code, we need to enable the `<uap:Capability Name="picturesLibrary" />` in the manifest file when you test this code.

Comment: If you have cached the list of files somewhere and want to make sure it works again when the grid/list is refreshed, add `thumbnail.Seek(0);` to the converter just before setting the source.